# Inputting two seperate lists and outputting a single list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following lists:

`l1=['R21', 'R21', 'R21', 'R22', 'R22', 'R22', 'R23', 'R23', 'R23']`

`l2=['T/T/T/T', 'G/G/G/G', 'CA/CA/CA/CA', 'G/G/G/G', 'TA/TA/TA/TA', 'T/T/T/T', 'TAA/TAA/TAA/TAA', 'C/C/C/C', 'T/T/T/T']`

I am wanting this as output:

`l3=[{'R21': 'T/T/T/T'}, {'R21': 'G/G/G/G'}, {'R21': 'CA/CA/CA/CA'}, {'R22': 'G/G/G/G'}, {'R22': 'TA/TA/TA/TA'}, {'R22': 'T/T/T/T'}, {'R23': 'TAA/TAA/TAA/TAA'}, {'R23': 'C/C/C/C'}, {''R23': 'T/T/T/T'}]`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this simple list comprehension:

```
l3 = [{k: v} for k,v in zip(l1, l2)]
```

And now:

```
print(l3)
```

Is:

```
[{'R21': 'T/T/T/T'}, {'R21': 'G/G/G/G'}, {'R21': 'CA/CA/CA/CA'}, {'R22': 'G/G/G/G'}, {'R22': 'TA/TA/TA/TA'}, {'R22': 'T/T/T/T'}, {'R23': 'TAA/TAA/TAA/TAA'}, {'R23': 'C/C/C/C'}, {''R23': 'T/T/T/T'}]
```